# how to get a word of indeterminate length from an array of char located between 2 characters?

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

Example:

> String phrase = "I want the word between /and? but how?";

I need:

String word = "and";

Even if there is more "/" and "?" I need the one that stands between the two.

i'm using java 1.8

There won't be spaces between the words if I do the right treatment, but if I can learn in a way that handles and without spaces, that would be great.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Simply indexOf and substring should help no? else regex?

Comment: i solved my problem using substring, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use Java Regex.

You didn't specify whether there would be spaces between the "/" word, or between the word and the "?". So let's assume the construct is: /word? (The word is stuck to the "/" and "?", and there is only one word in each set of "/" and "?".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/[a-zA-Z]+\\?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/one?  /two?"); //Your Text Here

String word;
while (matcher.find()) {
    word = matcher.group();
    word = word.replace("/", "");
    word = word.replace("?", "");
}
```

If you already expect one more word set that is between "/" and "?", you should create a list and add the String "word" inside:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/[a-zA-Z]+\\?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/one?  /two?"); //Your Text Here

List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
String word;
while (matcher.find()) {
    word = matcher.group();
    word = word.replace("/", "");
    word = word.replace("?", "");
    words.add(word);
}
```

Comment: now my problem has changed, i need to remove a word that comes after a slash and the end of the sentence but is still of undefined length.

example:
"/evaluate/subscribe"

I need the word: 
"subscribe" 

or any word after subscribe...